# mysql max and min subquery using date range

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
(Date + INTERVAL -(WEEKDAY(Date)) DAY) `Date`,
```

I would like to use a subquery here to get the oldest and newest inventory from the max and min Date:

`(select sellable from clabDevelopment.fba_history_daily where Date = 
  max(Date))`

```
max(Date), min(Date),
ASIN, 
ItemSKU, 
it.avgInv,
kt.Account, kt.Country, SUM(Sessions) `Sessions`, avg(Session_Pct)`Session_Pct`, 
sum(Page_Views)`Page_Views`,  avg(Page_Views_Pct)`Page_Views_Pct`,  avg(Buy_Box_Pct)`Buy_Box_Pct`, 
sum(Units_Ordered)`Units_Ordered`, sum(Units_Ordered_B2B) `Units_Ordered_B2B`,  
avg(Unit_Session_Pct)`Unit_Session_Pct`, avg(Unit_Session_Pct_B2B)`Unit_Session_Pct_B2B`,
sum(Ordered_Product_Sales)`Ordered_Product_Sales`, sum(Total_Order_Items) `Total_Order_Items`, sum(Actual_Sales) `Actual_Sales`,  
 sum(Orders) `Orders`, sum(PPC_Revenue) `PPC_Revenue`, sum(PPC_Orders) `PPC_Orders`,
sum(Revenue)`Revenue`,  sum(Sales_Tax_Collected) `Sales_Tax_Collected`,  sum(Total_Ad_Spend) `Total_Ad_Spend`, sum(Impressions) `Impressions`, 
 sum(Profit_after_Fees_before_Costs) `Profit_after_Fees_before_Cost`
FROM clabDevelopment.KPI_kpireport as kt

left outer join 
(SELECT Month(Date) as mnth, sku, account, country, avg(sellable)`avgInv` FROM clabDevelopment.`fba_history_daily`
where sellable  >= 0
group by Month(Date), sku, account, country) as it
on kt.ItemSKU = it.SKU
and kt.Account = it.account
and kt.Country = it.country
and it.mnth = Month(kt.Date)
WHERE kt.Country = 'USA' or kt.Country = 'CAN'
GROUP BY Account, Country,(Date + INTERVAL -(WEEKDAY(Date)) DAY), ItemSKU
ORDER BY Date desc
```

The sub-query would be from the same table I am joining on the bottom except I group by month there. So I want to run this subquery and grab the value under sellable for the date of max(Date):

```
(select sellable from clabDevelopment.`fba_history_daily where Date = max(Date))
```

When I do it this way I get invalid use of group function.

Comment: Reverse engineering SQL is pretty hard to do without knowing the source data. Share your tables as ascii data table or as sqlfiddle.com also share the expected result as a ascii data table

Answer (score 0):

Without known your schema and the engine/db it is difficult to understand the problem.  But, here is a best guess with the following schema:

```
fba_history_daily
- mnth
- sku
- account
- country
- sellable
- SKU

KPI_kpireport
- Account
- Country
- ItemSKU
- Account
- Date
- Country
- ASIN
```

The following query would give you what you're looking for.  This uses a GROUP_CONCAT in order to build the required results through aggregation.  With the nested query join MySQL might be building a temporary table within memory to sort through those records which would not be optimal.  You can check this using EXPLAIN and you would see `Using temporary` in the details.

```
SELECT
  (Date + INTERVAL -(WEEKDAY(Date)) DAY) `Date`,
  ASIN, 
  ItemSKU, 

  -- MIN
  (SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(it.sellable ORDER BY it.Date ASC),',', 1) AS minSellable),

  -- MAX
  (SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(it.sellable ORDER BY it.Date DESC),',', 1) AS maxSellable),

  -- AVG
  AVG(it.sellable) avgInv,

  kt.Account, kt.Country, SUM(Sessions) `Sessions`, avg(Session_Pct)`Session_Pct`, 
  sum(Page_Views)`Page_Views`,  avg(Page_Views_Pct)`Page_Views_Pct`,  avg(Buy_Box_Pct)`Buy_Box_Pct`, 
  sum(Units_Ordered)`Units_Ordered`, sum(Units_Ordered_B2B) `Units_Ordered_B2B`,  
  avg(Unit_Session_Pct)`Unit_Session_Pct`, avg(Unit_Session_Pct_B2B)`Unit_Session_Pct_B2B`,
  sum(Ordered_Product_Sales)`Ordered_Product_Sales`, sum(Total_Order_Items) `Total_Order_Items`, sum(Actual_Sales) `Actual_Sales`,  
  sum(Orders) `Orders`, sum(PPC_Revenue) `PPC_Revenue`, sum(PPC_Orders) `PPC_Orders`,
  sum(Revenue)`Revenue`,  sum(Sales_Tax_Collected) `Sales_Tax_Collected`,  sum(Total_Ad_Spend) `Total_Ad_Spend`, sum(Impressions) `Impressions`, 
  sum(Profit_after_Fees_before_Costs) `Profit_after_Fees_before_Cost`

FROM KPI_kpireport as kt

left outer join fba_history_daily it on 
  kt.ItemSKU = it.SKU
  and kt.Account = it.account
  and kt.Country = it.country
  and Month(it.Date) = Month(kt.Date)
  and it.sellable  >= 0

WHERE kt.Country = 'USA' or kt.Country = 'CAN'
GROUP BY Account, Country,(Date + INTERVAL -(WEEKDAY(Date)) DAY), ItemSKU
ORDER BY Date desc
```